# iostreams slow. Is there a way to speed them up?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, iostream

I've been hacking at a problem on and off for several days now that lists filenames that exceed the Windows `MAX_PATH` limit.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with all the patches I can find.  The timing is done with QueryPerformanceCounter and company.

The latest issue occurs in the following code:

```
    start = getTime();
    for( vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it )
    {
#if USE_COUT
            wcout << setw( 6 ) << it->length() << L": " << *it << endl;  // 1
#else
            wstring x( *it );
            wprintf( L"%6.6d: %s\n", it->length(), x.c_str() );          // 2
#endif
    }
    stop = getTime();
```

The above loop runs over a vector with 6755 entries with an average string length of 256 characters.

The code that prints via wcout takes roughly 52 seconds to display the vector using the loop above.  The code that uses wprintf prints in about 1.2 seconds.

If I minimize the console window the printf code runs in about 500 milliseconds while the wcout code still takes about 40 seconds.

I've really tried to like iostreams over the years, but...  I keep butting my head on this speed issue.  In 1993/1994 when using the Borland OS/2 compiler, we had a similar issue with a runtime that took 4 to 6 hours to complete using an strstream that ran in about 200 milliseconds with sprintf.

Any suggestions to get me to change my mind about iostreams?

---

Edit:
All this talk of flushing has me curious.
Isn't `\n` in a `printf` string functionally the same as `std::endl` in the sense that both cause a newline and flush to be emitted to the output?
IIRC, `printf` without a `\n` does not print on some OS's until a buffer is filled or the stream is flushed, including Windows in the past.
So, if `wprintf( "%6.6d: %s\n", length, string )` is flushed by the `\n`, why isn't `wprintf` as slow as `wcout`?

Thanks for your feedback/opinions.  I wish I had had SO 18 years ago when I started hacking at this stuff.

Comment: It could be the actual console that's slow, not your program. Do you get any speedup if you redirect the output to a file `yourprogram >file.txt` , or write to an actual file instead of wcout ?

Comment: What happens to the performance if you use `\n` instead of `endl`?

Comment: @nos: That sped things up quite a bit.  Down to just shy of 2 seconds when redirected.  I may have to work this into a batch file so the computer illiterate that will use it will not have to resort to command line redirection :)  Thanks

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Cuts down the time significantly as long as the console window is hidden.  If the console window is not hidden, it's about 800milliseconds to 1 second faster which seems weird.  Thanks.

Comment: @JimR: Can you be explicit about your timings. How much is significantly? And do you mean that it takes 40s + (0.8s ~ 1s) using '\n' if the console _isn't_ hidden?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Had to measure again.  18ish seconds with the console window hidden.  With the console Window visible, 39ish seconds. @Nawaz and @Rudi: The same goes for you 2, you made the same suggesstion.  It slightly more than halved the run time when the console is hidden to use "\n" instead of endl;

Comment: @JimR: which is nowhere near 1.2s which is more than a little disappointing, especially considering the `wprintf` version does an unnecessary `wstring` copy.

Comment: @JimR The output of printf and wprintf is buffered in different ways, depending on in which environment a program is executed. See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for more details (while the link shows details for unix, the buffering in windows is very similar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very likely that the `std::endl` line terminator is causing the performance bottleneck, since it flushes the stream after putting the newline. Exchange it with `'\n'` and a `std::wcout << std::flush` at the end of all output.

```
start = getTime();
for( vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it )
{
        wcout << setw( 6 ) << it->length() << L": " << *it << '\n';  // 1
}
std::wcout << std::flush;
stop = getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks, this sped things up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
  wcout << setw( 6 ) << it->length() << L": " << *it << endl;  // 1
```

One way to speed up is to use `"\n"` instead of `endl` in the loop, as `endl` is more than just a newline!

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing code to make it *less* likely that a human can keep up with the blur of scrolling lines of text doesn't make a lot of sense.  Rethink this approach.  Output to a text file, use HTML perhaps to make it look decent, then start a program to display the result.  Easier on your user's eyes.  It's going to run a *lot* faster as well, no auto-flushing and no time spent scrolling the console.  Only the disk I/O is your bottleneck now.

Comment: The program gives some summary info at the end which is what the user primarily wants to see.  The filenames are there so he can refer back to them if necessary.  The scrollback size for the console is set to max (9999 lines) and thats what he wants, so...  That's what he gets.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely to speed you up a lot by not flushing your stream every iteration (use '\n' rather than endl), although my guess is that you will still find printf to be faster.

You might move the setw outside of your loop too, by the way.

Comment: Moving `setw` outside the loop will mean that it will only be applied on the first iteration.